# Are there analogues of the spin-statistics theorem for other quantum numbers?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, spin-statistics

Just like how spin and statistics are connected by the spin-statistics theorem do the other quantum numbers (isospin etc.) enjoy any such relations?

Comment: The statistics only depends on particle spin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spin-statistics theorem is a consequence of the Lorentz group. It leaves internal symmetries, commuting with Lorentz, out.

You are essentially asking if boson states can be in antisymmetrically-composing representations of internal symmetry groups, e.g. if mesons can be isodoublets (isospin a half). Of course they can be: K-mesons, which are isodoublets. Symmetrically, the (fermion)  Σ baryons are isotriplet, i.e. they have integral isospin.

The only constraint in such situations is that the *generalized Pauli principle* obtains, namely fermion interchange dictating a totally antisymmetric wavefunction for the multistate constituents, so, overall spin-isospin-color-etc... antisymmetric.